# SQL UNION Question

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can someone explain to me why the SQL statement:

```
SELECT 'TEST1'
UNION SELECT 'TEST2'
UNION SELECT 'TEST3'
```

returns:

```
TEST2
TEST3
TEST1
```

I am trying to figure out the logic behind the `UNION` keyword in this aspect.
Is there a way I could get it to return:

```
TEST1
TEST2
TEST3
```

without using the `ORDER BY` clause? In other words, can I control the execution order of the `UNION` statements?

If it matters, I am using Postgre 9.0 and PHP as my language

Many thanks,
Brett

Comment: FYI - ms sql 08 returns 1, 2, 3 as I'd expect.

Comment: Without an ORDER BY the order of rows is **never** guaranteed. Even if you succeed with UNION ALL this can well change any time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [PostgreSQL docs for UNION](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/queries-union.html):

> UNION effectively appends the result of query2 to the result of query1 (**although there is no guarantee that this is the order in which the rows are actually returned**).

Comment: Perfect. Somehow I missed that in the doc even though it was right in front of me ;-) I guess I thought there was more to it that that. Many thanks! Green check for you.

Answer (score 4):

`UNION` semantics are that duplicates are removed. PostgreSQL is using a Hash function to remove the duplicates, and the results are comin out in the order of the key's hash.

You can use `UNION ALL`, but SQL still doesn't guarantee an order unless you use the `ORDER BY` clause.

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT 'TEST1'
UNION SELECT 'TEST2'
UNION SELECT 'TEST3'
```

Produces:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=0.07..0.10 rows=3 width=0)
  ->  Append  (cost=0.00..0.06 rows=3 width=0)
        ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 1"  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=0)
              ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0)
        ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 2"  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=0)
              ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0)
        ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 3"  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=0)
              ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0)
```

Whereas

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT 'TEST1'
UNION ALL SELECT 'TEST2'
UNION ALL SELECT 'TEST3'
```

Produces:

```
Append  (cost=0.00..0.06 rows=3 width=0)
  ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 1"  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=0)
        ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0)
  ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 2"  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=0)
        ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0)
  ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 3"  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=0)
        ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Most databases do not guarantee the order of anything without an `order by` statement.

union in most cases could allow the database to operate all 3 queries in parallel and return the rows as fast as possible.